# javascript - hour differences between two times

Tags: javascript, time

I need code in JavaScript which returns the time difference between two strings in hours.

Example, 
Strings are:
`20.07.2012, 01:00:00` and `22.07.2012, 15:00:00`:

A the result is 62 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var re = /[.:]|, /,
    date1 = "22.07.2012, 15:00:00".split(re).map(Number),
    date2 = "20.07.2012, 01:00:00".split(re).map(Number);


var diffMs = Date.UTC( date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0], date1[3], date1[4], date1[5] ) -
             Date.UTC( date2[2], date2[1] - 1, date2[0], date2[3], date2[4], date2[5] );

var hours = diffMs / (3600 * 1000);
//62
```

Comment: +1 for [UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

Comment: @user1562652 consider accepting the answer if your issue has been resolved. You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of this answer. Here's [more info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/174972):

Answer (score 1):

If available, I would suggest using Dojo Toolkit:
See http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dojo/date/difference

Comment: Like so: dojo.date.difference(d1, d2, "hour")